# adding events to wordpress full calendar via backoffice

Tags: jquery, wordpress, events, fullcalendar

I have successfully managed to integrate JQuery Full Calendar to my Wordpress site, but i want to be able to add events to the calendar via the backoffice rather than using a JSON file. Any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: what do you mean by "back office"? If you store the events in a database, then you can just query them and return the list in JSON format to fullCalendar. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i want the admin to be able to add events a visual interface like a plugin rather than using the json file

Comment: well you can use a fullCalendar instance itself to add events - you can drag and drop them onto the calendar and then it can send them to the server via ajax. If necessary you can add extra info via a custom form. Have you read the fullCalendar documentation which explains this? Alternatively you can write any GUI you like to do it, as long as it saves the events in a way that fullCalendar can then read (i.e. something which can have a valid JSON feed as its ultimate output, such as a database with a webservice in front of it).

Comment: Your JSON doesn't have to be in a static file, it can be generated on demand by the server. In fact that's probably the normal way to do it.

Comment: i have no prior experience with this whole subject and i am doing my best, can you please give me some further clarifications on how to add the events ??

Comment: it's far too broad a topic for an SO question. It would be a whole solution, not just an answer to a specific question. But I will give you a start: there are a few ways to do it, but the basic components you need are (cont'd)...:

Comment: 1) GUI for admin to enter event data. The fields and formats must be compatible with fullCalendar. You could even use a fullCalendar instance for this purpose if you like. 2) server-side script (e.g. PHP) which will receive the event data entered by admin and save it. 3) Place to store the event data. I would suggest a MySQL database. 4) server-side script (PHP again) which, when given a date range, will query the database for events in the range, and output the event data in JSON format recognised by fullCalendar. 5) point your existing fullCalendar "events" feed at your new script (item 4).

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ shows you how to point fullCalendar at a dynamic JSON feed to receive event data. The rest of the components can all be built using general programming skills, and it's hard to be more specific about what to do, it depends on your exact circumstances.

Comment: Another easier solution is using Google Calendar. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/ has details. In this case components 1-4 are all done for you by Google. It just depends if you are happy to store your data in Google's servers and for it to be publicly available.